# setImageViewUri doesn't show picture but show background of imageview

Tags: android, uri, android-imageview, android-appwidget

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/BabyCareData/photo/20160229_161413.jpg");
if (file.exists()) {
    views.setImageViewUri(R.id.imageAvatar, Uri.parse(file.getPath()));             
}
```

I have check the path and the uri,it is right.`setImageViewUri`doesn't show picture but show a white screen(background is white).

Comment: you have to create bitmap to set views.setImageViewBitmap(). give bitmap to function instead uri

Comment: @KhizarHayat I have try to use setImageViewBitmap(),but not prefect,it only works sometimes

Comment: have you made bitmap of given image ?

Comment: `views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageAvatar,BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/BabyCareData/photo/20160229_161413.jpg"))`

Comment: concider jas answer that is good

Comment: @KhizarHayat   how to  findViewById?  we can not get the viewgroup.so we can not     views.findViewById(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(/storage/emulated/0/BabyCareData/photo/20160229_161413.jpg);

if(file.exists())
{

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    setBitmap(views,R.id.imageAvatar,myBitmap);

}

    private void setBitmap(RemoteViews views, int resId, Bitmap bitmap){
        Bitmap proxy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(proxy);
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(resId, proxy);
    }
```

Comment: why not "setImageViewBitmap" ?

Comment: we don't know the viewgroup. so  `ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAvatar);` is error

Comment: the size of bitmap is too much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/BabyCareData/photo/20160229_161413.jpg");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageAvatar, bitmap);              
        }
```

Comment: sorry  I make a mistake, what i use is setImageViewUri,I have edited my question .thank you!